# Discrepancies between remote and local branches

Tags: git, github

I've encountered this strange issue where I have differences between the remote and local branches even after pushing changes.

Specifically, I will run the following:

- `git add foo.c`
- `git commit -m "Some message"`
- `git push`

Git doesn't produce any errors, but later when I check the remote repository on Github, some changes will not have propagated so that the local and remote copies of `foo.c` differ slightly. For example, some commented out lines that were deleted in the local copy will remain in the remote.

Running `git push`, `git fetch`, and `git pull` say things are up to date `git diff HEAD...origin/<remote-branch>` doesn't produce any output.

I've found that I can fix the issue by making a small change (such as adding a space) where there is a discrepancy, adding and committing the file again, and pushing.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this issue?

EDIT: To clarify, I have a remote origin (https://github.mit.edu/MITMotorsports/MY19) that I cloned locally. I then checked-out a new feature branch `low-pass`, made ~25 commits, pushed to origin (with `git push --set-upstream origin low-pass`, and then submitted a pull request. When reviewing the 'Files Changed' tab on github, I noticed the remote copy of `splitter.c` had most, but not all of the changes I had made to it. Trying to add, commit, and push the file again didn't fix the differences.

EDIT: I've specifically noticed this when submitting pull requests and comparing Github's list of files changed. But when I examine the remote version of branch, the discrepancy remains.

Answer (score 0):

Where to push? and what?

First of all you need to create a folder/repository to your github account on the web.

```
git remote add origin [address of your repository on guithub]

git push origin master (use this every time you want to push after adding)
```